# rsync How to preserve links on receiver

Tags: rsync

I've got dir per environment on receiver with links to some files.
This is because, some files are shared between environment.

So what I would like, when I'm doing a rsync from my remote host to my receiver, that the retrieve files are place following the links. But currently, my rsync replace my local links by the retrived files.

Is there a way to tell rsync to follow links on receiver hosts?

Comment: Possible anwer at https://superuser.com/questions/799354/rsync-and-symbolic-links

Comment: I saw this post, but it deals only with links on sender/source, not on receiver/destination. Here I'm looking to preverve links on destination. Let's say I'm rsync foo to my receiver where a foo link point to tmp/foo, I'd like that the content is copied in tmp/foo.

Answer (score 2):

If those links are pointing to directories, you cas use `-K` option which works flawlessly.

Other thing is when you have on the receiver links pointing to files (not dirs).
I am afraid, currently there is no simple way how to preserve the links in the destination and amend the files they are pointing to with the contents of local links/files those point to.

You might be interested in the `-L` option if you are sending files links from source but want to copy contents they point to rather than links themselves. However, this would also remove the corresponding links in the receive destination and as mentioned earlier, just change the files they are pointing to.

Check out https://serverfault.com/questions/245774/perform-rsync-while-following-sym-links for more information.